# Symfony2+Doctrine2 Entity Type selection

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have an Image entity:

```
class Image {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $location;

/**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
protected $file;

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getLocation()
}

//............
}
```

And I want to allow users to delete select images and delete them. I made an **ImageSelectType** :

```
class ImageSelectType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(PROBLEM_IS_HERE, 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'BloggerBlogBundle:Image',
            )
        )
        ;
}

//.......
}
```

However, I seem to be unable to understand exactly how Entity Type works. If I put 'location' or some property as first argument of *$builder->add* function, I get this for example:

```
object(Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Image)[316]
  protected 'id' => null
  protected 'location' => 
    object(Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Image)[79]
      protected 'id' => int 16
      protected 'location' => string '8a307aadd466f1b92b149d3f79069f5a1abc9cd3.png'     (length=44)
      protected 'file' => null
  protected 'file' => null
```

So It actually puts whole object into Location property of empty Image object. If I would have placed 'id' as first argument, I would get exactly the same result except object would be stored in $image->id. What am I supposed to enter as first argument of $builder-add to actually receive **just** the object itself?

Here is my action code if it's relevant:

```
public function imageDeleteAction()
{
$image = new Image();
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ImageSelectType(), $image);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    var_dump($image);
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a type just for Image, which breaks out it's properties in to separate fields, then use that AbstractType as the class for your other one.

You essentially want a [collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

## Update

I miss read your question a bit wrong the first time.

It looks like what you actually want to do is create something like an ImageGroup object which has an array of Images. Then that would be the target you send in to $this->createForm, and you would set that field in your PROBLEM_IS_HERE.

```
// Entity/ImageGroup.php
class ImageGroup
{
    protected $images;

    public function __construct($images) {
       $this->images = $images;
    }

    public function getImages() { return $this->image; }
    public function setImages($images) { $this->images = $images; }
}

// ImageSelectType
class ImageSelectType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('images', 'entity', array(
                    'class' => 'BloggerBlogBundle:Image',
            )
        )
        ;
}

// Controller
public function imageDeleteAction()
{
    $images = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('MyBundle:Image')->findAll();
    $imageGroup = new ImageGroup($images);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ImageSelectType(), $imageGroup);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    var_dump($image);
    exit;
}
```

Then you would have to loop through the images and figure out which ones are missing to delete them. There are a few variations on this method, but this is probably the simplest.

Comment: Oh....I thought of this but it just seems like using a dredger to pick up a pebble, overkill.....Is it not? I tried even like this, as you suggested, but symfony asks me to map ImageGroup in doctrine since it is an entity, and that would involve new database table and new complications......Should I just go with GET request sending the __id__ of selected image and make that manually? Something like mywebsite.com/admin/deleteimage/1234 ? And just use that id in imageDeleteAction to fetch the actual object ?

Comment: You don't have to map an Entity in to Doctrine. Using Doctrine on any given Entity is optional (unless you try to use getRepository on an image of that type). It does seem like overkill at first glance, but really having lots of small objects to handle things makes your code cleaner and more reliable, since PHP can then do very specific type checking for you (if you use type hinting). If you want to have a list and then delete it that way, it is also a valid approach (which I actually tend to use for my control panels).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got various interesting info from your answer(s) and learned how to handle these types of situations (which are very common)! I was getting "Doctrine not mapped entity" exception because I gave my 'class' option in entity form builder 'Bundle:ImageManager' instead of Image itself! I'll just post whole finished code here in case somebody stumbles upon similar problem. Symfony documentation is amazingly deep but even with it I find it to have a bit steep learning curve. Thanks again for your time and great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is finished code, which is 99% what @samanime suggested but still might be useful for somebody to see it completely done.

ImageSelectType buildForm function:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('images', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'BloggerBlogBundle:Image',
            )
        )
        ;
}
```

Controller "edit" page form:

```
public function imageEditAction()
{
    $uploadForm = $this->createForm(new ImageFileType());
    $selectForm = $this->createForm(new ImageSelectType());

    return $this->render('BloggerBlogBundle:Admin/Image:edit.html.twig', array(
        'uploadForm' => $uploadForm->createView(),
        'selectForm' => $selectForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Controller "delete" action:

```
public function imageDeleteAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $imageManager = new ImageManager();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ImageSelectType(), $imageManager);
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    $images = $imageManager->getImages();

    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $em->remove($image);
    }

    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('BloggerBlogBundle_admin_imageEdit'));
}
```

Comment: Note: If you are using Symfony 2.1 you can just use `$form->bind($request)` instead of `$form->bindRequest($request)` because `bind` function was introduced in 2.1 and is able to recognize if passed argument is request object.

Comment: Have you managed to phpunit test the form types using the entity class?

Comment: I haven't tried writing unit tests on any of the classes that inherit from Symfony ones unfortunately.

Comment: sorry for asking here, I have made another question about that but I am trying to find a solution on how to test form types using entity class :)